# the meaning of "just as dangerous"

Tags: meaning

*A narcissistic bully will face nationalist leaders just as dangerous. Prepare for a direct clash with China.*

https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2017/jan/21/president-trump-age-global-confrontation-nationalist-china

Can you explain to me the exact meaning of the first part of the above excerpt. Does it mean that a "narcissistic bully" (D. Trump) will in the next future clash with the similar class of politicians ("nationalists") that are as dangerous as him. I am not sure to which part "as dangerous" is connected.

Comment: **just as dangerous** complements **leaders**.  ...leaders (who are) just as dangerous (as the narcissistic bully is dangerous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passage is calling Trump a narcissistic bully, and goes on to say that he (a self-confessed nationalist leader with his "America First" address to the nation) is going to face others just like him, including [the leaders of] China.

Read it as:

> ... [he] will face nationalistic leaders [who are] just like him.